# Apache Pivot - "Main method not found in class"

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, pivot

I followed these instructions using the Eclipse IDE:

http://blogs.locusta.gr/argy/2011/09/setup-an-apache-pivot-project-in-eclipse/

So now I've imported and attached the respective Apache Pivot libraries. I tried to run this code they have on their website, but a proper main method is missing. Eclipse has underlined the first line of the code as an error.

This is the error I get:

```
Error: Main method not found in class HelloJava, please define the main method
as: public static void main(String[] args)
```

I understand the error, but what should the main method contain? https://www.mail-archive.com/user@pivot.apache.org/msg06027.html
This guy suggests the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DesktopApplicationContext.main(HelloJava.class, args);
}
```

But this returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
DesktopApplicationContext cannot be resolved
```

Anyone got any ideas? Here is the code, I'm pretty sure only the first bits are important:

```
package org.apache.pivot.tutorials;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import org.apache.pivot.collections.Map;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.Application;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.Display;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.Label;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.VerticalAlignment;
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.Window;

public class HelloJava implements Application {
private Window window = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
DesktopApplicationContext.main(HelloJava.class, args);
}

@Override
public void startup(Display display, Map<String, String> properties) {
    window = new Window();

    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Hello World!");
    label.getStyles().put("font", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    label.getStyles().put("color", Color.RED);
    label.getStyles().put("horizontalAlignment",
        HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    label.getStyles().put("verticalAlignment",
        VerticalAlignment.CENTER);

    window.setContent(label);
    window.setTitle("Hello World!");
    window.setMaximized(true);

    window.open(display);
}

@Override
public boolean shutdown(boolean optional) {
    if (window != null) {
        window.close();
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void suspend() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed it. I just had to erase the first line of the code, and add:

```
import org.apache.pivot.wtk.DesktopApplicationContext;
```